# When call View to another view backbone js events not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Whats the problem have to face  calling view to another view?...when i call the menu view to home view. Menu view not rendering properly. and big problem here that events not working !! but if call the menu view individualy then works  fine. i have question that whats the problem exacty in events and render template??

```
define([
  "jquery",
  "underscore",
  "backbone",
  "models/menu/MenuModel",
  "collections/menu/MenuCollections",
  "text!templates/menu/menuTemplate.html",
], function ($, _, Backbone, MenuModel, MenuCollections, menuTemplate) {

    var MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({       
        model: new MenuModel,  
        el:".sidebar_menu",    
        template: _.template(menuTemplate),
        events:{
            "click #sidebar .has-sub > a":"main_menu"
            },
        initialize:function(){         
             this.render();       
        },
        render: function () {                     
             this.$el.html(this.template());                            
          },
        main_menu:function(e){
            alert("rakib");
             var last = $('.has-sub.open', $('#sidebar'));
                last.removeClass("open");
                $('.arrow', last).removeClass("open");
                $('.sub', last).slideUp(200);
                var sub = $(e.target).next();
                if (sub.is(":visible")) {
                    $('.arrow', $(e.target)).removeClass("open");
                    $(e.target).parent().removeClass("open");
                    sub.slideUp(200);
                } else {
                    $('.arrow', jQuery(e.target)).addClass("open");
                    $(e.target).parent().addClass("open");
                    sub.slideDown(200);
                }

            }


    });

    return MenuView;

});
```

When i call menu view to home view..event is not working. whats the problem exactly ??

```
define([
  "jquery",
  "underscore",
  "backbone",
  "views/menu/MenuView",
  "models/home/HomeModel",
  "text!templates/home/homeTemplate.html",
], function ($, _, Backbone, MenuView, HomeModel, homeTemplate) {

    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({       
        model: new HomeModel,
        el: $("#container"),
        template: _.template(homeTemplate),

        initialize:function(){
          this.render();  
          this.menu_render();

        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
          },
        menu_render:function()
        {
          (new MenuView).render();  


        }



    });

    return HomeView;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to add your new view inside an html element of your current view to display it.
I would suggest to add your MenuView to an html element defined in your template file of your HomeView using an **append** function.

Like this:

```
$('#yourHomeViewHTMLElementDefinedInTemplate').append((new MenuView).render().el);
```

in your code try this:

```
    menu_render:function()
    {
      $("#container").append((new MenuView).render().el);
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Give a sample of where and how you call main_menu function.

Comment: MenuView :

events:{
            "click #sidebar .has-sub > a":"main_menu"
            }

 i appened it main (el)container homeview. MenuView event is not working in HomeView. 
main_menu:function(e)

Comment: try to change this "click #sidebar .has-sub > a" to something simpler like "click #nameOfElement": "main_menu", probably when appending the elements are inside other css classes. Try with a simple event in a direct html element of your menu view.